# How to quit appium driver and run another test without Session ID is null error

Tags: java, android, appium, driver, exit

I use BrowserStack. Before each test I create new driver. After each scenario I use `driver.quit()` because I want to close the session.

When I have more than one test case (e.g two scenario files) to run I get a message *Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?*.

When I don't use `driver.quit()` or I use `driver.closeApp()`, the first session takes too long and even if the second one starts, I cannot use it (I mean I cannot click on elements). I run my tests by junit runners.

Is there any possibility to quit driver after each test and run another one without that error?

```
private static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

@Before
public void before() {
    driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("URL"), capabilities);
}

public static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> getDriver() {
    return (AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver;
}

@After
public void after() {
   if ( driver == null ) {
       driver.quit();
       driver = null;
   }
}
```

Comment: are you facing this issue while you are running script in local or BrowserStack ?

Comment: @Mani on BrowserStack

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue, please go through the BrowserStack documentation for the Junit demo code [here](https://github.com/browserstack/junit-appium-app-browserstack/blob/master/android/junit5-examples/src/test/java/com/browserstack/run_parallel_test/BrowserStackJUnitTest.java), this is will help you solve the issue.
I can see your code mentioned "Before" & "After" only not "BeforeEach" / "AfterEach".

Please try this out

Comment: I see that in demo code there is @BeforeEach where you set up environment. Then you have static method to create driver and you use it in each test - [link](https://github.com/browserstack/junit-appium-app-browserstack/blob/master/android/junit5-examples/src/test/java/com/browserstack/run_first_test/FirstTest.java). In my case I think there is a problem that new driver still want to use previous session and I don't know why.

Comment: Basically, if you use only Before & After annotation which means the session will be a whole test suite which contains multiple tests, I think here session is not quit either create it's running the same session id for all your test cases give a try with "BeforeEach" / "AfterEach"

Comment: After each test, driver is null, I checked that. And new one is created before next test. With BeforeEach and AfterEach annotation I have a message _Can not set io.appium.java_client.MobileElement field to org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement_

Comment: If possible please post the entire appium log here, will check it

Comment: Thank you for your help. I resolved that. The problem was with elements. I didn't clear them after test and script wanted to use MobileElements from previous test..